# is there a way to add access modifier to a constant in php?

Tags: php, constants, access-modifiers

Is there a way to add access modifier to a constant inside a class or interface in php here is an example :

```
class A
{
 private const value = 20;//or protected
}

interface b
{
 protected const value = 100;//or private
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php Yes, as of 7.1.0

Comment: Oh okay thanks am using php version  7.0.9 thats why its not working